# Tab images not showing in the chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

For a while now in the chrome developer tools, the tab icons have not been showing. Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

This is what it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. They've changed the layout to be more compact.

You can set this back to the old default in the Developer Tools settings:

In the Developer Tools pane, click the gear icon:

[image]

Now, tick *Show Toolbar Icons*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not see the option in the settings. My dev tools look a lot better now :) (The icons help me to quickly see which one I want to click on) Marked as the answer and upvoted

Comment: The option does not appear in Chrome 30. I think they may be gone for good now.

Answer (score 4):

This option was removed from Chrome in version 30.

You can no longer set toolbar icons, unless one is provided in an unofficial theme for the devtools: http://devthemez.com/themes/chrome-developer-tools?sort=popular